# Android XmlPullParser error

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I've found good example how to parse XML in android.com. Here is part of

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

```
private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException     {
    String link = "";
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "link");
    String tag = parser.getName();
    String relType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "rel");
    if (tag.equals("link")) {
        if (relType.equals("alternate")) {
            link = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
            parser.nextTag();
        }
    }
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "link");
    return link;
}
```

It can correctly parse when there is only one LINK tag in one single  tag. But it output error when there is so many LINK in single  tag.

Please let me know how to fix this coding to parse multiple LINK tags in one single  tag.

Comment: pls post log what exactly error is coming.

Comment: ... and an example input you want to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting the error unless if you tell us what the error is but as far as checking the tags go, you need to fix it with a while loop:

```
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "NameOfParentTag"); //Tag name which "link" tags are embedded in
String link = "";
while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        continue;
    }
    String tag = parser.getName();
    String relType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "rel");
    if (tag.equals("link")) {
        if (relType.equals("alternate")) {
            link = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
            //Break here if you are done looking for what you need
        }
    }
}  
return link;
```

It'd be helpful if you also provided an example XML that you want to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the parser.nextTag() snippet to the outer if statement like this:

```
if (tag.equals("link")) {
    if (relType.equals("alternate")) {
        link = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
    }

    parser.nextTag();
}
parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "link");
return link;
```

Answer (score -1):

use documentparser instead of xmlpullparser.u got a mistake at statement parser.nexttag().use parser.next() which will check for next link value.